# Use regex to match 5 num, dot, 1 num, dot, 5 num

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to create regex to match the following pattern:

```
00000.1.17372
```

i.e: `5 Numbers DOT 1 Number DOT 5 Numbers`

I have tried the following re.match:

```
find = re.match('d{5}.d{1}.d{5}', string)
```

In context:

```
import re

string = "{u'blabla': u'asdf', u'dd': u'a', u'cotry': u'jjK', u'l': u'/q/iii:00000.1.17372', u'stfe': u'', u'fdfhdiufhi': u'GB', u'y_name': u'Unitm', u'mw': u'00000.1.17372'}"

find = re.match('d{5}.d{1}.d{5}', string)

print find
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as the output is:

```
None
```

Comment: `re.match(r'^\d{5}\.\d\.\d{5}$', string)`

Comment: Use `search` instead. `match` only works at the beginning of a string.

Comment: This matches 'ddddd#d#ddddd'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following with `re.findall`:

```
r'\b\d{5}\.\d\.\d{5}\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ExVBOp/1)

The point is:

- to match a digit, you need to use `\d`
- a dot must be escaped to match a literal dot
- to match whole words, you need to use `\b` word boundary or you will find matches of 5-digit chunks in `2234567654` like strings
- `re.findall` will return a list of all non-overlapping matches (since there are no capturing groups in this pattern)

Sample Python code:

```
import re
regex = r"\b\d{5}\.\d\.\d{5}\b"
test_str = "{u'blabla': u'asdf', u'dd': u'a', u'cotry': u'jjK', u'l': u'/q/iii:00000.1.17372', u'stfe': u'', u'fdfhdiufhi': u'GB', u'y_name': u'Unitm', u'mw': u'00000.1.17372'}"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'To match whole words', when there are no words included? :) Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Whole word matching means there are no "word" chars before or after the value. "Word" chars include letters, digits and underscore (~`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` - depending on the `re.UNICODE` flag).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is:

```
\d{5}\.\d\.\d{5}
```

You need to escape the dots and use the proper token for a number, which is `\d`.